# Lost access to AWS RDS SQL Server, I only have 1 login, and cannot change permissions

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Amazon RDS User Permissions

When accessing my DB using Toad i get an error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tables', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

I am unable to use this database anymore. I know its because I messed with the permissions of that user. However I cannot figure out how to modify the permissions again. I don't have another user I can log in as and set those permissions.

I thought this reset would do it. But it does not.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.ResetPassword.html

Anyone know how to reset permissions, so that I can use this database again?

Comment: Yeah. Ask the admin to do it. Otherwise, you know, ask Amazon Support - THEY have admin access, right?

Answer (score 0):

I reloaded from an AWS RDS snapshot.  Wow, i was freaking out for a bit.